# No access to files on CIFS filesysem

Tags: permissions, kubuntu, cifs

I try to access a SMB filesystem from Kubuntu 22.04. The SMB filesystem runs on a NAS fileserver under FreeBSD. The files on this filesystem were created with Win7.
On Kubuntu I mount this filesystem with mount.cifs .
Mounting works, I can see folders and files, but opening a file gives an ACCESS DENIED error.
uid and gid are set to my local user.
I choose smb version 1.0, because higher version is not accepted by the fileserver.
With WIN7 I can access the files without errors.

Entry in /etc/fstab:

```
//magicnas/Bilder /home/guenther/NASBilder cifs vers=1.0,noacl,rw,nolinux,uid=1000,gid=1000,forceuid,forcegid,noperm,noauto,domain=WORKGROUP,user=xxxxxxx,pass=xxxxx,file_mode=0750,dir_mode=0755 0 0
```